# how to get dynamically the id from list - flutter

Tags: list, flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-onpressed

I have a cardView list `DUMMY_CATEGORIES` on my homepage called from a category model with an `id`.
I want to pass the `id` in my homepage and then open a new page performing a onPressed method.

How can I do that?

**This is my Homepage**

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return new Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
    title: Text('Pocket Chef'),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
  body: GridView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
    children: DUMMY_CATEGORIES.map((categoryItem) => CategoryItems(
      categoryItem.name,categoryItem.icon)).toList(),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2,
          mainAxisSpacing: 20,crossAxisSpacing: 20
      ),
    ),
);
```

**And this is my DUMMY_CATEGORIES**

```
const DUMMY_CATEGORIES = const [
Category(
  name: "Category 1", id: "1", icon: Icons.food_bank),
Category(
  name: "Category 2", id: "2", icon: Icons.food_bank ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use ***Gridview.builder*** insist of **GridView**. Gridview.builder has some special fetaure than **Gridview**. Builder takes dynamic content. You can put action on gridview item easily. My solution is given below...

```
  return GridView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        gridDelegate:
            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemCount: DUMMY_CATEGORIES
            .map((categoryItem) =>
                CategoryItems(categoryItem.name, categoryItem.icon))
            .toList()
            .length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen(CategoryItems(categoryItem.name, categoryItem.icon))
                      .toList()[index].id.toString())));
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              child: Text(
                'click on here',
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
```

**Recieve** the **id** from second page like this..
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class NewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  String something;

  NewScreen(this.something);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return NewScreenState(this.something);
  }
}

class NewScreenState extends State<NewScreen> {
  String something;

  NewScreenState(this.something);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        //now you have passing variable
        title: Text(something),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Text(widget.something.toString()),
      ),);
  }
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks a lot. I think it is what i was looking for, but i have a questions.
-  i don't have to pass anything on new screen, so can we delete the string "CategoryItems(categoryItem.name, categoryItem.icon)).toList()", ?

also because i get error : The return type String isn't a widget.

Comment: yes u can delete from MaterialPageRoute call like this  Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen( ))); and remove constructor and parameter  from new screen as well. remove below variable and constructor.

String something; 
NewScreen(this.something);

Comment: Nice! it works. But then all the card(category) will open the same page. In Java android, we have a if statement, so i can open a different page for each card. 
For example, if id = 1 open page 1, if id = 2 open page 2... etc..
how can i do  the same in flutter?

Comment: u can set if else or switch condition in  ontap method. suppose as like as
      onTap: () {
        if(index ==0){
          Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreenZero()));
          }else if(index ==1){
          Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreenOne()));
        }
        else if(index ==2){
          Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreenTwo()));
        }
        ...........etc
        },

Comment: Thanks a lot. But gridview builder does not show the category model items. After the if statement, i have to implement a child to create the view.
If i create child: Column (widjet[icon, text]), i don't know how to pass the category model.
 im not able to call them, i got an error. i added the Dummy categories to the ```itemCount``` property, but im still not able to receive the icons and titles from ```category model```. why it is that?